# Return type of function in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I created a generic java function to read a list of files. The function is created in HdfsClient class, then I should call it in another class, I loop the list of the files and I open them.

Function code:

```
public listeFileHdfs(String hdfsPath) 
    {
        if(hdfs!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                Path HdfsPath = new Path(hdfsPath);
                
                this.hdfs.listFiles(HdfsPath, false); **==> listFiles() is a defined function in HDFS client**
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                logger.error("files not exist:", hdfsPath, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
         
        
    }
```

My question, does this function should take a return type ? If yes which type should it `List<String>`, `List<JSON>` or just `void` ?

Comment: Well, currently the method doesn't return anything, so `void` seems appropriate.

Comment: Is your method supposed to ***return*** any values? If no, then it's return type is `void`.

Comment: My need is: I should list all the files in HDFS Path. So I created this function to list the files, I used the pre-defined function listFiles to return the list files. Then I should use it this function to loop on the list files and open them. How can you do it ? Thanks

Comment: Normally the pre-defined listFiles return all the list files. So, then How can I loop on the list files ?

Comment: @PM77-1 did you understand my need please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you expect the function does. Here is how I would decide the function signature.
If you want to extract the list of files from JSON format and convert it into simpler one and, possibly, make it available for the invoker, I would change the name of the function and return `List<String>`, like this:

```
public List<String> getListFileHdfs(String hdfsPath)
```

On the other hand, if the function is supposed do some internal elaboration with that list of files, I would change the name of the function and return void:

```
public void elaborateListFileHdfs(String hdfsPath)
```

Moreover, if you just want to print out the list of the files, I would leave the name as it is and return `void`.

[EDIT]
To answer your question in the comment, I suggest that you leave `String` as input, which is the path of the Hadoop directory. Your function should look like as follow:

```
public List<String> getListFileHdfs(String hdfsPath) 
{
    List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    
    if(hdfs!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            Path HdfsPath = new Path(hdfsPath);
            
            RemoteIterator fileIter = hdfs.listFiles(new Path(path), recursive);
            
            while (fileIter.hasNext()) {     
                String filePath = ((LocatedFileStatus) fileIter.next()).getPath().toString();
                paths.add(filePath);   
            } 
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            logger.error("files not exist:", hdfsPath, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
     
    return paths;
}
```

Comment: In case we choose public List<String> getListFileHdfs(String hdfsPath) the return in the end what should take as value ? My function is above, I used the pre-defined function listFiles. That's all what I put.

Comment: The simple `String` should be ok. In my understanding, the `hdfsPath` input variable is the full path of the Hadoop directory, isn't it?
Bear in mind that the function `listFiles` returns a `RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus>` iterator, so you have to add some extra code to get your `List<String>`, something like this:

`RemoteIterator fileIter = hdfs.listFiles(new Path(path), recursive);
  while (fileIter.hasNext()) {
    String filePath = ((LocatedFileStatus) fileIter.next()).getPath().toString();
    paths.add(filePath);
  }` Sorry for the formatting, her is not the same as the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have an idea about my question please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66170146/how-create-a-jsonarray-in-java

Comment: There are many ways to convert a List<String> into a JSONArray. Here is some example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66170146/how-create-a-jsonarray-in-java

Answer (score 3):

### Can user decide the context?

```
    interface Base<T> {
        List<T> get();
    }

    class Derived implements Base<Integer> {
        public List<Integer> get() {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

1. If the user can infer the context of the returned type (based on multiple implementations of your class), and the method is always expected to return a list, then

`List<T> listeFileHdfs(String hdfsPath)`

In this case,

1. the user can expect an implementation that will return file names as String as `List<String>`
2. the user can expect an implementation that will not return anything as `List<Void>`
3. the user can expect an implementation that will return Custom object as `List<CustomObject>`

Alternatively, the type based simply `T` which gives bigger flexibility for implementations but causes a greater abstraction that should be resolved correctly by the end user.
`T listeFileHdfs(String hdfsPath)`

1. This gives flexibility to return any type
2. though increases flexibility will add complexity for code maintainers

So, you can choose this based on expected use case.

### Updated based on comment

1. `List<?>` - returning this will be make it difficult for the consumers to infer the type.
2. if `?` is to be used, it will be good to bound to a type, say `List<? extends SomeType>`

eg: This allows bounded(compile time controlled) inserts to the list

```java
  List<? super Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(1);
```

This does not allow inserts to the list (nearly nothing)

```java
  List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(new Object()); // this will be compile time error
  list.add(null); // this is only allowed
```

This does not allow inserts too, but has type safety for usage

```java
List<? extends Number> anything = somefunction_returning_a_subclass_of_number();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I didn't understand in case of the function have a return type. the return in the end should take which value ? Knowing that the content of the files is a JSON

Comment: Good one, I agree with you @Horse.