# How create a JSONArray in java

Tags: java, arrays, hdfs

I have 2 java functions:
`listeFilesHdfs` return a list of files that stored in HDFS, for example:

If you remark, the files that stored in HDFS  there content is a JSON format, for example:

```
{
"name":"Name",
"type":"string"
},
{
"name":"Version",
"type":"string"
},
{
"name":"r_service",
"type":"string"
},
{
"name":"r_timestamp",
"type":"long"
},
```

I created the below function to call both function above (one return list of files and the second open a path):

How can I modify my function to read the files content and to add each file content to the JSON array and return an array of JSON ?
Thanks

Comment: There is a vivid ecosystem of open source JSON-APIs in Java. Depending (strongly) on your use case (how to operate on the json array) you can choose between various different ones. I personally still like javax.json https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html because it offers modifiable json objects, but that is ultimately your own choice. (And there are good reasons not to use javax.json).

Comment: @TreffnonX I'm using JSONArray. But I'm looking how to fill it by the files content.

Comment: @lsabelle which `JSONArray` class? There are multiple APIs that use this class-name. What are you importing, when you have a `JSONArray` object reference?

Comment: @TreffnonX I imported import javax.json.Json; And I changed the function signature like this: public <JSONArray>JSONArray getSchema(). And inside I added JSONArray array = new JSONArray(); ==> Here I got an error cannot instantiate the type JSONArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As by your comment answer, you are looking for a way to parse the json content of the files into a javax.json-`JsonArray`.

The answer is the class `JsonReader`.
As per the documentation:

> ```java
> JsonReaderFactory factory = Json.createReaderFactory(...);
> JsonReader reader = factory.createReader(...);
> JsonStructure content = Jsonreader.read();
> ```

That JsonStructure could then be a JsonArray (and you may cast to it, after checking the class).

It might work like this (though I can't test it):

```java
public JSONArray getSchema()
{
    String avroSchemaHDFSDir = "hdfs://hadoopcluster/schemas";

    try(HdfsClient hdfsClient = new HdfsClient(nameNodeHosts, hadoopZks))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < hdfsClient.listeFilesHdfs(avroSchemaHDFSDir).size(); i++)
        {
            String fileContent = hdfsClient.listeFilesHdfs(avroSchemaHDFSDir).get(i).toString();
            hdfsClient.openHdfsPath(file);
            JsonReaderFactory factory = Json.createReaderFactory(...);
            JsonReader reader = factory.createReader(...);
            JsonStructure content = Jsonreader.read();
            if (content instanceof JsonArray) {
                return (JsonArray) content;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.debug("get the specified schema ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;     
}
```

Comment: How can I integrate them in my function ? My function should return a JSON array. Should I use one of the jsonReader ?

Comment: @lsabelle, yes, you should use the JsonReader to read the JsonStructure (from a file or a string-based stream) and then cast that to a JsonArray (assuming it is one).

Comment: I think you're expert in Java. could you please publish an example according my function. I'm new in java. thanks

Comment: @lsabelle, Are you absolutely certain, that you import `javax.json` and *not* `org.json`? Because `JSONArray` is a name used in `org.json` and others, but *not* in `javax.json`.

Comment: yes I imported javax.json, but it's ot working. So, could you please give a solution. you have my need, and my function above. how can I can modify it to return an array of json as result.

Comment: My function openHdfsPath  that open a Path, it return nothing (void). Should I change it to String as return type ? to be able to add its value to the JsonObjectBuilder ?

Comment: I don't know the hdfs-API, so I can't help you on how to the the files themselves. But once you have the content of a single file, you can use the JSONReader, as described above, to instantiate the array (or JsonStructure...).